Rocket-Chip generator environment setup
I tried to set up the rocket-chip generator environment. I cloned the git repository and updated the submodules as follows:
$ git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip.git
$ cd rocket-chip
$ git submodule update --init

Then, I ran make verilog as per the guide. However, I encountered the following error:
rocket-chip/dependencies/chisel/build.sc:416: type Module is not a member of object mill.define.Cross
trait Lit extends tests.LitModule with Cross.Module[String]
... (so many errors)
I have no idea why this error is occurring. Can anyone help me?
Please guide me how to set up the environment.
I tried update submodules.

Maybe you need a recursive checkout:
git submodule update --init --recursive


First of all, thank you for answering me.
I tried it, but there is another issue on it.
common.sc:33: type ScalaTest is not a member of object mill.scalalib.TestModule
with TestModule.ScalaTest {
^
Compilation Failed
There is a compile issue, but I don't know why this issue occurs.

This is just a Scala unit test. It should not affect the running code.
You could go into a sub directory and modify the build.sbt file to include ScalaTest there, if this problem is preventing the code to run.

I see references to some petty old Scala repos. Maybe an old Scala test lib version is not longer maintained.
